# Generate random numbers in increments

Tags: java, c++, c, random

I need to generate `n` random numbers between `a` and `b`, but any two numbers cannot have a difference of less than `c`. All variables except `n` are floats (`n` is an int).

Solutions are preferred in java, but C/C++ is okay too.

Here is what code I have so far.:

```
static float getRandomNumberInRange(float min, float max) {
    return (float) (min + (Math.random() * (max - min)));
}

static float[] randomNums(float a, float b, float c, int n) {
    float minDistance = c;
    float maxDistance = (b - a) - (n - 1) * c;
    float[] randomNumArray = new float[n];
    float random = getRandomNumberInRange(minDistance, maxDistance);
    randomNumArray[0] = a + random;
    for (int x = 1; x < n; x++) {
        maxDistance = (b - a) - (randomNumArray[x - 1]) - (n - x - 1) * c;
        random = getRandomNumberInRange(minDistance, maxDistance);
        randomNumArray[x] = randomNumArray[x - 1] + random;
    }
    return randomNumArray;
}
```

If I run the function as such (10 times), I get the following output:

Input: `randomNums(-1f, 1f, 0.1f, 10)`

`[-0.88, 0.85, 1.23, 1.3784, 1.49, 1.59, 1.69, 1.79, 1.89, 1.99]`

`[-0.73, -0.40, 0.17, 0.98, 1.47, 1.58, 1.69, 1.79, 1.89, 1.99]`

`[-0.49, 0.29, 0.54, 0.77, 1.09, 1.56, 1.69, 1.79, 1.89, 1.99]`

Comment: is there a problem with what you have? Also, you didn't ask a question.

Comment: and what is wrong with your code, that you're not satisfied with it ?

Comment: @retrodone Its actually to randomly generate platforms in my game, as two platforms can't be too close to each other, not homework.

Comment: Question edited to show incorrect output.

Comment: You're really asking for trouble with the problem as you've put it. Do you need to generate a solution with a minimum number of platforms despite the possibility that if chosen badly they won't all fit between a and b? I'd just place a platform, go a random distance greater than c, and place another platform.

Comment: if c is in a similar order as a and b, I would just do the check in a while loop to simplify the implementation, but that is just me

Comment: If I understand what you are something adds some random increment to a and then interates that, but what happens if the first number generated is greater than b - c? You can't generate any more numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think a reasonable approach can be the following:

[image: schema]

1. Total "space" is `(b - a)`
2. Remove the minimum required space `(n-1)*c` to obtain the remaining space
3. Shot `(n-1)` random numbers between 0 and 1 and scale them so that the sum is this just computed "optional space". Each of them will be a "slice" of space to be used.
4. First number is `a`
5. For each other number add `c` and the next "slice" to the previous number. Last number will be `b`.

If you don't want first and last to match `a` and `b` exactly then just create `n+1` slices instead of `n-1` and start with `a+slice[0]` instead of `a`.

The main idea is that once you remove the required spacing between the points (totalling `(n-1)*c`) the problem is just to find `n-1` values so that the sum is the prescribed "optional space". To do this with a uniform distribution just shoot `n-1` numbers, compute the sum and uniformly scale those numbers so that the sum is instead what you want by multiplying each of them by the constant factor `k = wanted_sum / current_sum`.

To obtain the final result you just use as spacing between a value and the previous one the sum of the mandatory part `c` and one of the randomly sampled variable parts.

An example in Python of the code needed for the computation is the following

```
space = b - a
slack = space - (n - 1)*c
slice = [random.random() for i in xrange(n-1)]  # Pick (n-1) random numbers 0..1
k = slack / sum(slice)                          # Compute needed scaling
slice = [x*k for x in slice]                    # Scale to get slice sizes
result = [a]
for i in xrange(n-1):
    result.append(result[-1] + slice[i] + c)
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, except for one slight change: remove the length of `(n-1)` slices, generate `n` (distinct) numbers, and insert the slices between the numbers (the first and last number won't be at `a` and `b` but random).

Comment: Still falls victim to the early selections altering the distribution of latter selections.  A few large slices at the beginning of the selection process can guarantee you will never select another equally large slice.  In effect the latter selections demonstrate a decreasing variance.

Comment: @Edwin I don't think so. If you take `n-1` random numbers, sort them, and scale their range then there's no meaning to "beginning" and "end" of the selection process. But I suspect there's still a problem because the 2 outliers have so much influence on the other numbers.

Comment: @Edwin: please read carefully. By picking N-1 random numbers and **scaling them** so that the sum is exactly the space to distribute the distribution will be uniform (on the part above the minimum). Random picking and sorting would not give a uniform distribution of slices of slack space. I didn't use sort exactly for this reason. I'll add the exact slice vector computation code to make it clearer.

Comment: @6502 Yes, please add some code (or even pseduocode) to this, as I've having a little trouble understanding the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! Works well. If you have time though, could you explain how the last for loop works? Like, why is it able to perform what it does?

Comment: @AmandeepGrewal: In python accessing an array with a negative index means "from the end". More specifically `result[-1]` is the last element of the `result` array. In C++ that is equivalent to `result[result.size()-1]` or `result.back()`.

Comment: @6502 Yup, I knew that, but how does it make sure the numbers are evenly distributed?

Answer (score 2):

If you have random number X and you want another random number Y which is a minimum of A from X and a maximum of B from X, why not write that in your code?

```
float nextRandom(float base, float minDist, float maxDist) {
  return base + minDist + (((float)Math.random()) * (maxDist - minDist));
}
```

by trying to keep the base out of the next number routine, you add a lot of complexity to your algorithm.

Comment: If you're greedy and take almost all of the remaining space on your first number, there won't be room for the minDists for the rest.

Comment: There's no guarantee under the current algorithm that this doesn't happen either.  In fact, it is not possible to generate truly random numbers according to the algorithm and always meet the criteria.  If randomness is really important, best to generate a set of ten numbers and check it to see if it meets the criteria, throwing away undesirable sets.

Comment: the original algorithm does assure that it can generate n numbers, just had a small bug, see my answer. it does *not* create uniform distribution though

Answer (score 1):

Though this does not exactly do what you need and does not incorporate the techinque being described in this thread, I believe that this code will prove to be useful as it will do what it seems like you want.

```
static float getRandomNumberInRange(float min, float max)
{
    return (float) (min + (Math.random() * ((max - min))));
}
 static float[] randomNums(float a, float b, float c, int n) 
{
    float averageDifference=(b-a)/n; 
    float[] randomNumArray = new float[n];
    int random;
    randomNumArray[0]=a+averageDifference/2;
    for (int x = 1; x < n; x++)
        randomNumArray[x]=randomNumArray[x-1]+averageDifference;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        random = getRandomNumberInRange(-averageDifference/2, averageDifference/2);
        randomNumArray[x]+=random;
    }
    return randomNumArray;
}
```

Comment: I will test this and the others posted tonight.

Comment: You'll get too nice a distribution, with one platform in every bin.  However, it might not be a bad thing for the application considered.  Also, your algorithm fails unless there is a lot of empty space ((b - a) > 2 * n * c), but again that's OK for the numerical example given in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to generate n random numbers between a and b, but any two numbers cannot have a difference of less than c. All variables except n are floats (n is an int).
>
> Solutions are preferred in java, but C/C++ is okay too.

First, *what distribution*? I'm going to assume a uniform distribution, but with that caveat that "*any two numbers cannot have a difference of less than c*". What you want is called "rejection sampling". There's a wikipedia article on the subject, plus a whole lot of other references on the 'net and in books (e.g. [http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-ARM.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-ARM.pdf)). Pseudocode, using some function `random_uniform()` that returns a random number drawn from U[0,1], and assuming a 1-based array (many languages use a 0-based array):

```
function generate_numbers (a, b, c, n, result)
  result[1] = a + (b-a)*random_uniform()
  for index from 2 to n
    rejected = true
    while (rejected)
      result[index] = a + (b-a)*random_uniform()
      rejected = abs (result[index] < result[index-1]) < c
    end
  end
```

Comment: I guess you are also assuming that you are sorting `result` when adding an element.  You should also check if it rejected  by looking at the left and right neighbors.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming anything of the such. The OP didn't specify what "any two numbers cannot have a difference of less than c" means. I assumed any two adjacent numbers. If the OP meant something different clarification is needed.

Comment: Then shouldn't you check all pairs `abs (result[i] - result[j]) < c`?  When you generate a new result it can be to the left of the previous ones since they are all generated with `a + (b-a)*random_uniform()`.

Comment: @David Sorry I meant no two numbers generated can be less than `c` apart.

Comment: @Amandeep: What are you trying to accomplish? What problem are you trying to solve? If the underlying process is discrete, use a discrete distribution. If the underlying process, well there is no physical process that I know of that will generate anything close to such a distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by just generating n random numbers between a and b.  Then I would sort them and get the first order differences, kicking out any numbers that generate a difference less than c, leaving me with m numbers. If m < n, I would just do it again, this time for n - m numbers, add those numbers to my original results, sort again, generate differences...and so on until I have n numbers.

Note, first order differences means x[1] - x[0], x[2] - x[1] and so on.

I don't have time to write this out in C but in R, it's pretty easy:

`getRands<-function(n,a,b,c){
   r<-c()
   while(length(r) < n){
      r<-sort(c(r,runif(n,a,b)))
      r<-r[-(which(diff(r) <= c) + 1 )]
   }
   r`

}

Note that if you are too aggresive with c relative to a and b, this kind of solution might take a long time to converge, or not converge at all if  n * C > b -a

Also note, I don't mean for this R code to be a fully formed, production ready piece of code, just an illustration of the algorithm (for those who can follow R).

Comment: will this generate equal distribution? will it ever finish if (n_1)*c is close to b-a? I doubt it.

Comment: I also think that there is an infinite loop possibility. If a=0, b=1, c=0.1, and n=10, and the numbers generated were 0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 7.5, 9. Now you only have 7 numbers but cant insert another number anywhere.

Comment: @Amandeep, that is a fundamental flaw with the way the problem is specified.

Comment: @yi_H It could be uniformly distributed.  However I guess you would need to add the condition that when an interval is too short you reject the value at the start or end of the interval with 50-50 probability. Even then, I'm not sure it's enough for uniformity.  It might be simpler to just generate `n` values and if there is a conflict than start over with `n` new values.  But that would take even longer to reach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was almost correct, here is the fix:

```
maxDistance = b - (randomNumArray[x - 1]) - (n - x - 1) * c;
```

Comment: I changed my two maxDistance lines to: `float maxDistance = b - (n - 1) * c;` and `maxDistance = b - (randomNumArray[x - 1]) - (n - x - 1) * c;`. Output here: http://pastie.org/pastes/2275548/text?key=vlh81hmpi1eqb91w5agiq In summary, the first number is always -0.9, and there are not enough negative numbers to be random.

Comment: nonono, the first maxDistance was fine! *just* fix what I've told

Comment: Similarly, if I don't touch my first maxDistance, I get this output (not enough negative numbers): http://pastie.org/pastes/2275614/text

Comment: right..:/ it fixed the bug but the main concept is flawed, it won't generate uniform distribution

Comment: Ya, I didn't say my algorithm was on the right track, just the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a shifting range as you generate numbers to ensure that they don't appear too close?

```
static float[] randomNums(float min, float max, float separation, int n) {
    float rangePerNumber = (max - min) / n;

    // Check separation and range are consistent.
    assert (rangePerNumber >= separation) : "You have a problem.";

    float[] randomNumArray = new float[n];

    // Set range for first random number
    float lo = min;
    float hi = lo + rangePerNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        float random = getRandomNumberInRange(lo, hi);

        // Shift range for next random number.
        lo = random + separation;
        hi = lo + rangePerNumber;

        randomNumArray[i] = random;
    }
    return randomNumArray;
}
```

Comment: Your distribution will be heavily skewed to the left.

Comment: Agreed.  I wasn't sure this wasn't homework so I left in a deliberate error :).  The issue is reducible by recalculating `rangePerNumber` anew for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer, but I like this problem. I hope it's unique, I haven't gone through everyone's answers in detail just yet, and I need to run, so I'll just post this and hope it helps.

Think of it this way:  Once you pick your first number, you have a chunk +/- c that you can no longer pick in.

So your first number is

```
range1=b-a
x=Random()*range1+a
```

At this point, x is somewhere between a and b (assuming `Random()` returns in 0 to 1).  Now, we mark out the space we can no longer pick in

```
excludedMin=x-c
excludedMax=x+c
```

If x is close to either end, then it's easy, we just pick in the remaining space

```
if (excludedMin<=a)
{
  range2=b-excludedMax
  y=Random()*range2+excludedMax
}
```

Here, x is so close to a, that you won't get y between a and x, so you just pick between x+c and b.  Likewise:

```
else if (excludedMax>=b)
{
   range2=excludedMin-a
   y=Random()*range2+a
}
```

Now if x is somewhere in the middle, we have to do a little magic

```
else
{
  range2=b-a-2*c
  y=Random()*range2+a
  if (y>excludedMin) y+=2*c
}
```

What's going on here?  Well, we know that the range y can lie in, is 2*c smaller than the whole space, so we pick a number somewhere in that smaller space.  Now, if y is less than excludedMin, we know y "is to the left" of x-c, and we're all ok.  However, if y>excluded min, we add 2*c (the total excluded space) to it, to ensure that it's greater than x+c, but it'll still be less than b because our range was reduced.

Now, it's easy to expand so n numbers, each time you just reduce the range by the excluded space among any of the other points.  You continue until the excluded space equals the original range (b-a).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's bad form to do a second answer, but I just thought of one...use a recursive search of the space:

Assume a global list of points: `points`

```
FillRandom(a,b,c)
{
  range=b-a;
  if (range>0)
  {
    x=Random()*range+a
    points.Append(x)
    FillRandom(a,x-c,c)
    FillRandom(x+c,b,c)
  }
}
```

I'll let you follow the recursion, but at the end, you'll have a list in `points` that fills the space with density 1/c